# JMX connection, using basic auth, failure

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmx

my problem is that I can't establish a remote connection using basic authentication like username\password when working with JMX using VisualVM 2.1.6

so here is configuration:

1. Java\Catalina opts

```
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.10.101.28 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9596 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/conf/management/jmxremote.password'
```

2. jmxremote.password file

[jmxremote.password file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzT5a.png)

3. jmxremote.access file

[jmxremote.access file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf28V.png)

So, if -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate set to false, connection from my local maschine to remote host (in local network) establishes with no any troubles, as soon auth is enabled, getting always

[sad picture of VisualVm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3RAn.png)

p.s. i`am already have tried jConsole, it also has same behavior

i almost sure, that file is ok, because when i set up clear password, after connection attempt it rewrites to hashed password automatically.

Comment: what happens when you give incorrect password in the clear? error or login dialog?

Comment: nothing changes, getting same @sad picture of VisualVm@

Comment: ok that means errors get swallowed without feedback...you should look at the error logs and see what the actual error says, otherwise it's like trying to hit mosquitoes in the dark